# Can Java use matlab plot funtion in a while loop to dynamically plot point and keep the change in one figure without create a new figure every time?

Tags: java, matlab

I have a problem with my matlab-java mixed programming. I have packaged one of my matlab m file named plotDisData.m to a java jar file, which this file includes.

```
  hold on
  plot(dx, dy,'ob')
```

I used this jar file in my java code which is:

```
public void server(MathUtil mu) throws IOException, MWException {

        int port = 8888;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true) {
            if(mu.getDisplacement().size() == 150)break;
            System.out.println("server waiting for you");
            Socket socket = server.accept();

            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((len = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
              sb.append(new String(bytes, 0, len,"UTF-8"));
            }
            System.out.println("get message from client: " + sb);
            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)JSONObject.parse(sb.toString());
            Accelerometer accel = new Accelerometer();

            accel.setAx(jobj.getDoubleValue("ax"));
            accel.setAy(jobj.getDoubleValue("ay"));
            accel.setAz(jobj.getDoubleValue("az"));
            mu.computeVelocity(accel);
            Displacement dis = mu.computeDisplacement(accel);

            dx = dis.getDx();
            dy = dis.getDy();

            MatlabPlotter mp = new MatlabPlotter();
            mp.plotDisData(dx, dy);


            socket.getOutputStream().write(dis.toString().getBytes());
            socket.getOutputStream().flush();
            List list = mu.getDisplacement();
            System.out.println("get message from client: " + sb);

            inputStream.close();
            socket.close();
            server.close();
        }
  }
```

I put this java code in a while loop and keep plot point(dx, dy). This code creates every time a figure to plot new point, but what I want is to plot all points in just one figure.
Although I put "hold on" command in matlab code, it seems that this does not work in java. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? This does almost kills me....

Comment: Post the full code for the Java method containing the while loop.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing the Java code but my guess is that you are calling `plot` in `matlab` for every single point. If that's the case, instead you can generate the data first and then pass an two `arrays` of data to `plot(xarray, yarray, 'ob')`

Comment: thanks for your reply. plot(xarray, yarray, 'ob') is not my purpose, because i want to plot the realtime dynamic track of all points. the whole idea of my code is first i get accelerometer sensor's data (ax , ay, az)from my android phone and send data to my eclipse via socket, after computation, i get displacement (dx ,dy dz) , then i use matlab plot jar file to draw this point , all these i do in a while(true) loop since i want to plot the point in a dynamic way